# Как в битриксе сделать что то типа "Товары которые вы смотрели" ?

Tags: php, битрикс

Для проекта требуется на страничке выводить фото товаров списком которые мы просмотрели ранее, вот и задумался я как такое можно реализовать. В маркет плайсе есть такой компонент (стоит 300руб) а демо просмотра нету. То есть функционал этот можно сделать, но как? в куки писать пользователю `id` товаров, которые он просмотрел? Потом дергать их? По моему мнению не - лучший метод. Подскажите, пожалуйста, светлые головы.

Comment: Может в таблицу к пользователям добавить колонку, куда будут записываться ID товарох, которые он посмотрел последними...

Comment: Не совсем понял вас

Comment: Похоже случай битрикс-программиста, когда кроме стандартных компонентов ничего не умеют использовать. Печально.
Нужно на детальной запоминать DETAIL_ID в сессию, создать компонент "Вы смотрели...", в нем получать товары по этим ID

Comment: да вы правы не умею, действительно печально... умел бы, здесь бы не спрашивал.
Теперь по делу.
спасибо за хорошую идею.

Comment: Бывает, тоже когда-то не умел, потом понял сколько проблем с битриксом бывает, что не хочется больше связываться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SESSION` - ваше все. Дерзайте.